# IIS 7.5 returning 403 in WebDAV PROPFIND request

Tags: iis-7.5, webdav

I am configuring an IIS 7.5 server for WebDAV.  When the client application issues a anonymous PROPFIND request to read the directory contents, the server returns a 403 Forbidden status.  I need it to return a directory listing.  What do I need to do to fix this?  We have this working correctly on an IIS 6.0 server.

Set Up:

1. A virtual directory has been created that points to a share on a file server.  IIS is configured to connect using as specific account.
2. WebDAV has been installed, and enabled.
3. WebDAV annonymous property requests have been enabled.
4. A WebDAV rule has been created on the virtual directory above to allow read requests for all content and all users.
5. Only annonymous authentication is enabled.

Troubleshooting:

- If I browse the directory using IE, I get a directory listing, so the directory browsing works.
- The IIS Failed Request Log contains the following entries:

  ```
  No.  Severity   Event                                                                             Module Name 
  93   Warning    -MODULE_WARNING                                                                   WebDAVModule
                  ModuleName          WebDAVModule
                  Data1               Invalid Depth: For PROPFIND Not Allowed Due To Configuration
                  Data2
                  ErrorCode           0
                  ErrorCode           The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
  94   Warning    -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS                                                 WebDAVModule
                  ModuleName          WebDAVModule
                  Notification        128
                  HttpStatus          403
                  HttpReason          Forbidden
                  HttpSubStatus       22
                  ErrorCode           0
                  ConfigExceptionInfo
                  Notification        EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
                  ErrorCode           The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under WebDAV Settings, I needed to set "Allow Property Queries with infinte Deptth" to True.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  In my case I'd set the Webdav Authoring Rules to allow read, write & source access to `*.kmz` files; all worked for `put`, `get`, and `delete` requests, but `propfind` failed.  The issue was that `propfind` was searching all files, so didn't have access to search (even though there were no other files there).  Enabling access for all file types resolved the issue.